# Copy and paste to different worksheets

Tags: performance, vba, excel

This code:

1. Copies a value from `"Sheet1"`
2. Pastes special (as a number) in another sheet `"Sheet2"`
3. Jumps to the next line

I already:

1. Disabled screen refresh
2. Wrapped the code with `Application.EnableEvents = False`  and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

   `1` made the calculation a little faster, but `2` didn't seem to make any effect.

```
Dim iterations, counter As Integer
iterations= 10000
counter = 1

Do While counter <= iterations

' copy value from Sheet1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Copy

' paste value in sheet2
Sheets("Sheet2").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

counter = counter + 1

Loop
```

I usually run 50,000+ iterations (`counter = 50000`).

How can I improve this code speed?

Comment: hi @m3dl and welcome to Code Review. We can review your code as-is but we could probably help even more if you provided the entire `Sub` that it runs in.

Comment: What exactly is your objective? If the copy is always going to be the same, you can simply move the `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Copy` before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

if your aim is to:

- copy the value in cell "B4" of worksheet "Sheet1"
- and paste it in worksheets "Sheet2" from cell "A1" downwards in `iterations` cells

then simply use:

```
Dim iterations: iterations = 1000    
Worksheets("Sheet2").range("A1").Resize(iterations).value = Worksheets("Sheet01").range("B4").value
```

if your aim is to:

- copy the value from cell "B4" of worksheet "Sheet1" and down to `iterations` cells
- and paste them in worksheets "Sheet2" from cell "A1" downwards in `iterations` cells

then simply use:

```
Dim iterations: iterations = 1000    
Worksheets("Sheet2").range("A1").Resize(iterations).value = Worksheets("Sheet01").range("B4").Resize(iterations).value
```

Comment: The first option is my objective. Your code worked, but it pastes the same value in the 1,000 lines. I would like to recalculate the spreadsheet before get the value of `B4`, since its value changes with a `=RAND()` function. So, I need to recalculate the spreadsheet using `Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Calculate`, but I don't know how to use this .calculate in your answer.

Comment: is your aim simply to have `iterations` random numbers in "Sheet2" from cell "A1" downwards?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explained myself in a clear way. Not exactly. `B4` is a VLOOKUP that depends on a RAND() fuction, so `B4` changes value when the spreadsheet is recalculated.

Comment: then you speed issue is totally derived from sheet calulations speed. The only way to improve it is take all that calculations off the sheet and into VBA code